# Macro assigning formulas to whole column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have written the following macro:

```
Sub assigningFormulas()

Dim i As Integer
Dim table1 As ListObject
Dim table2 As ListObject    

Set table1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Segments")    
Set table2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("SegmentValues")

For i = 2 To table1.Range.Rows.count    
    Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=" & Cells(table2.TotalsRowRange.Row, i + 3).Address(False, False, xlR1C1, True, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2))        
Next i

End Sub
```

It is supposed to assign formulas to cells in a column of table1 to be equal to the values in the corresponding cells on the Totals Row of table2. Basically, I have the totals in table2 on a row and I want to copy them (by reference, not by value) on a column in table1.

The problem is that at every step it assigns new formulas to the whole column of table1 down to the current cell. Only the current cell gets the right value. The other cells get the value of cells on the same column as the current cell on the Totals Row in table2.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Added screenshots:
[image: table2]
[image: table1]

Comment: It's not clear the cells refference between the 2 tables. Can you share a screen-shot of your tables, and show with lines which cells from `table2` should go to which cell in `table1`

Comment: I added the screenshots of the whole table1 and of the Header and Totals Rows of table2. Both tables start at column 1. table1 starts at row 1 and table 2 starts at row 24.

Comment: What is the structure of table2 ?

Comment: The problem is with how tables work in general. A calculated column will have one formula for the whole column by default. There are ways around it, but it's tricky. So, the best thing to do is a make a formula that fits in all cases. In a few moments I will have the answer for that posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in my comment the issue is that by design calculated columns in Excel Data Table (ListObjects) will apply to the entire column.

There are two solutions. 1) Override the default behavoir or 2) Create a single formula that can successfully accomplish the results on each row in the column.

Since solution 2 is relatively easy in this case, I will demonstrate it below.

First a picture done manually, so you can understand. Notice the `INDEX` in the Allocation column of Table 2 that uses the Totals Row of Table 1 as the Range and a match for Segment on Table 1 Headers Rows to determine the column to find. Structured Referencing makes this very easy to read and understand.

[image]

Equivalent VBA to enter this formula is:

```
With Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2").ListColumns("Allocation").DataBodyRange
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX(Table1[#Totals],MATCH([@Segments],Table1[#Headers],0))"
End With
```

And another beauty is that there is no need to loop :) Using Excel's built-in functionality with VBA is **very powerful**.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer proved to be most useful!

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure what column does `table1` start, and what columns does `table2` start, but once you get the ***Delta Columns*** between them, you can use the code below:

```
For i = 2 To table1.Range.Rows.Count
    table1.Range(i, 2).Formula = "=" & Cells(table2.TotalsRowRange.Row, i + 3).Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)
Next i
```